# python list comprehension in nested loops

Tags: python, list-comprehension

One basic question in list comprehension as i am starting on that,

can a list comprehension return two arrays?

like I was trying to convert my code to list comprehension

```
b=[10,2,3]
c=[10,11,12]
d=[]
f=[]
a=10
for i in b:
    if a>i:
        for j in c:
            d.append(j)

print d
```

I am able to convert the above code using list comprehension as

```
print [j  for i in b if a>i  for j in c ]
```

But now I want to add an extra else block to my initial code and looks like

```
b=[10,2,3]
c=[10,11,12]
d=[]
f=[]
a=10
for i in b:
        if a>i:
            for j in c:
                d.append(j)
        else:
          f.append(i)
print d
print f

d=[10, 11, 12, 10, 11, 12]
f=[10]
```

is there any way  I can add this extra else to my initial list comprehension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use a list comprehension for your second example, because you are *not building a single list*. List comprehensions build **one** list object, not two.

You could use two separate list comprehensions:

```
d = [j for i in b if a > i for j in c]
f = [i for i in b if a <= i]
```

or you could simplify your loops a little by using `list.extend()` or `+=` augmented assignments:

```
for i in b:
    if a > i:
        d.extend(c)
    else:
        f.append(i)
```

or

```
for i in b:
    if a > i:
        d += c
    else:
        f.append(i)
```

Comment: `You can't use a list comprehension for your second example`. [Challenge accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46827604/6419007).

Comment: @EricDuminil: yes, you can produce multiple sequences and unpack. You can use `zip()` too. It is never *readable*, however.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question :

> Can a list comprehension return two arrays?

Yes, it can:

```
>>> [[1] * n for n in [3, 5]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> d, f = [[1] * n for n in [3, 5]]
>>> d
[1, 1, 1]
>>> f
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Just for fun, here's a one-liner to define both `d` and `f`:

```
d, f = [[j for i in b if f(i) for j in g(i)] for (f, g) in [(lambda x: x < a, lambda x: c), (lambda x: x >= a, lambda x: [x])]]
```

It's obviously a bad idea, though, and @MartijnPieters's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825278/python-list-comprehension-in-nested-loops/46825312#46825312) is preferable.

Comment: You've answered the question, shown code and outputs, and simultaneously shown just because one can does not mean one should.  Challenge accomplished!